# glsl shader passing and rendering texture

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I'm trying to pass and use a texture to shader... but every time I try to use it in even the easiest way I get black box, sometimes white - depends on the texture I put him.. somehow....

Here's code fragment witch should work ( i've removed my wrappers to make it easier):

```
fbo->bind();
fbo->drawBuffer(0);
fbo->setClearColor( 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
fbo->cleanCurrentTexture();

GLuint location;
location = glGetUniformLocation( Program->getID(), "sampler");
glActiveTexture( GL_TEXTURE0 );
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo2->getTexture(0) );
glUniform1i(location, 0);
Program->begin();
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f );
    glVertex3f( -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
    glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f );
glEnd();

Program->end();

fbo->unbind();

glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, fbo->getTexture(0) );
    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
         glTexCoord2d( 0.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f );
         glTexCoord2d( 0.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f( -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
         glTexCoord2d( 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
         glTexCoord2d( 1.0f, 0.0f);
        glVertex3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f );
    glEnd();
glDisable( GL_TEXTURE_2D);
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 120

void main()
{
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 120

uniform sampler2D sampler;

void main()
{   
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(sampler, gl_TexCoord[0].xy);
}
```

Ofcourse the texture I'm trying to bind exists and its complete. Here are it's parameters:

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameterf( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE );
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_GENERATE_MIPMAP, GL_TRUE);
```

Comment: WHat happens if you output some other fixed color in the fragment shader?

Comment: It must be something stupid somewhere - and I can't find what. I tried with a couple of textures.. even with some raw ones loaded strait from the file using SOIL library, and every time I just get a solid color fill - taken from the texture. And its every time the same color for the same texture, taken from different part - but usually from the top right corner (1,1). The funny thing is, that shaders, texturing, FBOs and other stuff work fine, Please help.. you're my last hope :(

Comment: I think that the problem is that you need to set the texture coordinates when you render the quad to the FBO.

Comment: Btw: Better avoid using the fixed function pipeline, this would make your code faster and your life easier at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as Plow says in his comment, I believe this has to do with texture coordinates not being set. You are only setting texture coordinates for the second quad. The second quad is not being drawn with the shader program either, and it is being drawn in the exact same coordinates as the first, which means it should be either completely white (because `glColor3f(1.0,1.0,1.0)`), or it should not be drawn at all (depending on your camera position and whether or not depth testing is enabled).

Try drawing only the first quad, with texture coordinates properly set up.

Comment: Yep... that was it!
I was looking for long hours for some hardcore bugs in my code, in spite of looking for some ease one first...
My friend found it after 5min of looking on my code.. but thank you anyway for precious help! =]

Comment: Hehe, nice. :) No problem!